# Edit individual metadata in layout.js file

Tags: next.js

I want to be able to edit a page's custom metadata and fit it in to a template in layout.js

/page.js:

```
export const metadata = {
    title: 'Home',
    description: 'Description Example',
}
```

/layout.js

```
export const metadata = {
    title: `App Name | ${metadata.title}`,
    description: metadata.description,
}
```

So the title for `/` be "App Name | Home", and the description would be "Description Example"

This is my first Next/React project so I'm still getting my bearings with things.
Thanks.